# Bootstrap hamburger menu issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web, hamburger-menu

I'm having an issue on my website (www.pnxau.me), where the first time use of the 'hamburger menu', closes, then opens, then afterwards works as intended.

Can I have some assistance solving this bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share some code. At least the init function...

Comment: Don't worry, I fixed it. Although you can still look at the code yourself on the website (inspect element/view-page source).

Answer (score 0):

All good, fixed it.

Simply changed the default `class="navbar-collapse collapsed"` to `class="navbar-collapse collapse in"` - when loaded/by default, through code it was seen as 'closed'.